# Обыватели - способ образования слова?

Tags: словообразование

От слова БЫВАТЬ?

Answer (score 1):

Суффиксальный: от "обывать"-проживать, обитать.

Во многих словах приставки срослись с корнем и как самостоятельные части слова уже не выделяются.